# DevicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp Method Not Working Properly

Tags: java, android, mobile, device-policy-manager

I want to put my application in pinned screen mode. And I want a permission from user for this.

[Permission Notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AYmO.jpg)

But I don't always want to show this statement to user.

I found the **setLockTaskPackages()** method in the Android 5.0 Api document.

[Android 5.0 Api's](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0)

```
private void provisionOwner() {
    DevicePolicyManager manager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    ComponentName componentName = DeviceAdminSample.getComponentName(this);

    if(!manager.isAdminActive(componentName)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        return;
    }

    if (manager.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
        manager.setLockTaskPackages(componentName, new String [] {getPackageName()});
        startLockTask();
    }
}
```

I also checked device owner list with this;

> manager.getActiveAdmins()

and I see my package Id in admins list.
Here is settings screen admin list
[My app(Teacher App) is device admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScA8r.jpg)

But  `isDeviceOwnerApp(myPackageName)` methods getting `false`

Why this method getting false and I can't pass the permission screen although My app is a device admin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Device admin is not the same as device owner, there is many steps to achieve it. You can start research from [official doc](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/prov-devices)